# How to call a method inside a Ruby class definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to enhance my `ActiveRecord` models with a function that creates a type of `scope` or `validation` or whatever for particular fields on that model. I like to be able to do something like:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include MyCustomeBehavior

  my_custom_behavior :field_1, :field_2, ...
end
```

I'm looking at the `ActiveSupport::Concern` module and I would like to do something like:

```rb
module MyCustomeBehavior
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Where do I put this method so I can call it FROM INSIDE
  # the class definition of MyModel?
  def my_custom_behavior(*args)
    # gather the fields that I'm passing to this method from my model and then call the code below in the "included" block
  end

  included do
    # Ideally, I want to select these fields using a method like the one above.
    [:field_1, :field_2, ...].each do |field|
      # I want to be able to create my own scopes or validators or whatever
      # and I want to select particular fields for this based on whats passed to
      #
      # my_custom_behavior :field_1, :field_2, ...
      #
      # in my MyModel class.
      scope field ...
      validates field ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a class method:

```rb
module Mod
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.also_class_method
      p "also class method"
    end
  end

  class_methods do
    # you can use `private` here
    def class_method
      p "class method"
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class MyModel
  include Mod

  class_method
  also_class_method
end

"class method"
"also class method"
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html*

Answer (score 1):

The methods in the class definition are executed in the context of the class.

So your "macro method" needs to be a class method:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  extend MyCustomeBehavior

  my_custom_behavior :field_1, :field_2, ...
end
```

When you `extend` a class with a module its instance methods become class methods. Using `ActiveSupport::Concern#class_methods` its nothing but superflous syntactic sugar in this case as what it does is just:

```
module MyCustomeBehavior
  module ClassMethods
    def my_custom_behavior(*args)
      # ...
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end 
end
```

This does make sense if you're providing both class and instance methods from the same module. But in that case its an easy refactor later.

Comment: "Macro method", a great way of describing what I'm trying to do and thanks for the explanation of what `ActiveSupport::Concerns` is doing under the hood. +1

Comment: "Macro method" is not really an official term but in Ruby its commonly used to denote  the pattern of class methods which mutate the class (add methods/variables/include modules etc) - `attr_accessor` is a good example.